# Efficient memcpy of large input in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, memcpy, gpu

I have a problem with a program I'm writing using CUDA. I have an input array and an output array which I need to copy to device memory. The problem is that both arrays together are too large to fit in the device memory. What I'm doing now is splitting both input and output array and run the kernel sequentially for both parts. 
In order for this approach to work I use an intermediate array, since the cudaMemcpyFromArray and cudaMemcpyToArray only seem to work for Texture Memory. This leads to unneccesary memory copy operations. Does anyone know a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use asynchronous memory copy if operations on one segment of the array are independent of operations on another segment of the array. This will help you copy things back and forth while doing computation. From cuda c programming guide:

> some function calls are asynchronous: Control is returned to the host
> thread before the device has completed the requested task. These are:
>
> - Kernel launches;
> - Device to device memory copies;
> - Host to device memory copies of a memory block of 64 KB or less;
> - Memory copies performed by functions that are suffixed with Async;
> - Memory set function calls.

You could also consider compressing arrays using rice coding to make them fit.